# Express/HTTP listen EADDRINUSE for every port?

Tags: node.js, linux, express, socket.io, centos7

This is quite weird i tried at least 30 ports on a CentOS 7 server for the express application and i keep getting:

```
Uncaught Exception:  listen EADDRINUSE :::1238
[ERROR] Stack Trace:  Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::1238
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1253:14)
```

I tried various different ports and i am pretty sure that nothing is using these ports but i keep getting this error.

Here is my express code:

```
import http from 'http';
import express from "express";
import compression from 'compression';
import SocketIO from "socket.io";

let App = express();
let HTTPServer = http.Server(App);
let Socket = new SocketIO(HTTPServer);
App.use(compression({}));
HTTPServer.listen(1238, function() {
    console.log("Listening.."); 
});
```

I checked firewall is off, nothing should block the application. I have one more application runnig on port 8080 just fine. And i just can't get this one working. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes... since the http server handles socket.io. look into the protocol if you dont know how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your process doesn't stop while you are stopping your program in those ports.
try to run these commands in your terminal.

```
lsof -i:<your port number>
```

If you got a table then it means your process is not killed, copy that PID from that table and run this command

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

this will kill the process running on that port, after this, you can use this port for your program.

I have tested these commands in ubuntu, I don't know about CentOS, but both are Linux so you can try this.

Comment: I checked and indeed my process was running as a child process for gulp and that caused so i missed the process in the list.

Comment: And my processes were automatically started when i edited a file :)